# AngularJS doesn't work into Electron

Tags: angularjs, electron

I have an AngularJS app that works perfectly. Is there any reason why the app doesn't work into Electron? I don't want to bother you with all the code, just searching for tips after hours spent around the internet. Thank you all.

Comment: You need to check the network errors. It's likely that js path is wrong